# Faster way to find the first TRUE value in a vector

Tags: r, performance

In one function I very often need to use code like:

```
which(x==1)[1]
which(x>1)[1]
x[x>10][1]
```

where `x` is a numeric vector. `summaryRprof()` shows that I spend >80% of the time on relational operators. I wonder if there is a function that does comparison only till the first `TRUE` value is reached to speed up my code. For-loop is slower than the options provided above.

Comment: `which.min` and `which.max` consider a similar problem.

Comment: @James: not quite, because they require a logical vector and creating the logical vector is what is time-consuming.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Base R provides `Position` and `Find` for locating the first index and value, respectively, for which a predicate returns a true value. These higher-order functions return immediately upon the first hit.

```
f<-function(x) {
  r<-vector("list",3)
  r[[1]]<-which(x==1)[1]
  r[[2]]<-which(x>1)[1]
  r[[3]]<-x[x>10][1]
  return(r)
}

p<-function(f,b) function(a) f(a,b)
g<-function(x) {
  r<-vector("list",3)
  r[[1]]<-Position(p(`==`,1),x)
  r[[2]]<-Position(p(`>`,1),x)
  r[[3]]<-Find(p(`>`,10),x)
  return(r)
}
```

The relative performance depends greatly on the probability of finding a hit early relative to the cost of the predicate vs the overhead of `Position/Find`.

```
library(microbenchmark)
set.seed(1)
x<-sample(1:100,1e5,replace=TRUE)
microbenchmark(f(x),g(x))

Unit: microseconds
 expr      min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval cld
 f(x) 5034.283 5410.1205 6313.861 5798.4780 6948.5675 26735.52   100   b
 g(x)  587.463  650.4795 1013.183  734.6375  950.9845 20285.33   100  a

y<-rep(0,1e5)
microbenchmark(f(y),g(y))

Unit: milliseconds
 expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
 f(y)   3.470179   3.604831   3.791592   3.718752   3.866952   4.831073   100  a 
 g(y) 131.250981 133.687454 137.199230 134.846369 136.193307 177.082128   100   b
```

Comment: `Position` and `Find` are just syntactic sugar for a `for` loop. Not that there's anything wrong with that, just that the OP mentioned that a `for` loop was slower.

Answer (score 21):

I don't know of a pure R way to do this, so I wrote a [C function](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/quantstrat/src/firstCross.c?view=markup&revision=1571&root=blotter) to do it for the quantstrat package.  This function was written with a specific purpose in mind, so it's not as general as I would like. For example, you may notice that it only works on real/double/numeric data, so be sure to coerce `Data` to that before calling the `.firstCross` function.

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>

SEXP firstCross(SEXP x, SEXP th, SEXP rel, SEXP start)
{
    int i, int_rel, int_start;
    double *real_x=NULL, real_th;

    if(ncols(x) > 1)
        error("only univariate data allowed");

    /* this currently only works for real x and th arguments
     * support for other types may be added later */
    real_th = asReal(th);
    int_rel = asInteger(rel);
    int_start = asInteger(start)-1;

    switch(int_rel) {
        case 1:  /* >  */
            real_x = REAL(x);
            for(i=int_start; i<nrows(x); i++)
                if(real_x[i] >  real_th)
                    return(ScalarInteger(i+1));
            break;
        case 2:  /* <  */
            real_x = REAL(x);
            for(i=int_start; i<nrows(x); i++)
                if(real_x[i] <  real_th)
                    return(ScalarInteger(i+1));
            break;
        case 3:  /* == */
            real_x = REAL(x);
            for(i=int_start; i<nrows(x); i++)
                if(real_x[i] == real_th)
                    return(ScalarInteger(i+1));
            break;
        case 4:  /* >= */
            real_x = REAL(x);
            for(i=int_start; i<nrows(x); i++)
                if(real_x[i] >= real_th)
                    return(ScalarInteger(i+1));
            break;
        case 5:  /* <= */
            real_x = REAL(x);
            for(i=int_start; i<nrows(x); i++)
                if(real_x[i] <= real_th)
                    return(ScalarInteger(i+1));
            break;
        default:
            error("unsupported relationship operator");
  }
  /* return number of observations if relationship is never TRUE */
  return(ScalarInteger(nrows(x)));
}
```

And here's the R function that calls it:

```
.firstCross <- function(Data, threshold=0, relationship, start=1) {
    rel <- switch(relationship[1],
            '>'    =  ,
            'gt'   = 1,
            '<'    =  ,
            'lt'   = 2,
            '=='   =  ,
            'eq'   = 3,
            '>='   =  ,
            'gte'  =  ,
            'gteq' =  ,
            'ge'   = 4,
            '<='   =  ,
            'lte'  =  ,
            'lteq' =  ,
            'le'   = 5)
    .Call('firstCross', Data, threshold, rel, start)
}
```

Some benchmarks, just for fun.

```
> library(quantstrat)
> library(microbenchmark)
> firstCross <- quantstrat:::.firstCross
> set.seed(21)
> x <- rnorm(1e6)
> microbenchmark(which(x > 3)[1], firstCross(x,3,">"), times=10)
Unit: microseconds
                  expr      min       lq    median       uq      max neval
       which(x > 3)[1] 9482.081 9578.072 9597.3870 9690.448 9820.176    10
 firstCross(x, 3, ">")   11.370   11.675   31.9135   34.443   38.614    10
> which(x>3)[1]
[1] 919
> firstCross(x,3,">")
[1] 919
```

Note that `firstCross` will yield a larger relative speedup the larger `Data` is (because R's relational operators have to finish comparing the entire vector).

```
> x <- rnorm(1e7)
> microbenchmark(which(x > 3)[1], firstCross(x,3,">"), times=10)
Unit: microseconds
                  expr      min        lq    median        uq        max neval
       which(x > 3)[1] 94536.21 94851.944 95799.857 96154.756 113962.794    10
 firstCross(x, 3, ">")     5.08     5.507    25.845    32.164     34.183    10
> which(x>3)[1]
[1] 97
> firstCross(x,3,">")
[1] 97
```

...and it won't be appreciably faster if the first `TRUE` value is near the end of the vector.

```
> microbenchmark(which(x==last(x))[1], firstCross(x,last(x),"eq"),times=10)
Unit: milliseconds
                         expr      min       lq   median       uq       max neval
       which(x == last(x))[1] 92.56311 93.85415 94.38338 98.18422 106.35253    10
 firstCross(x, last(x), "eq") 86.55415 86.70980 86.98269 88.32168  92.97403    10
> which(x==last(x))[1]
[1] 10000000
> firstCross(x,last(x),"eq")
[1] 10000000
```

Comment: Check that: firstCross(as.numeric(1:100),as.numeric(200),"gte"). I would expect an Error or NA, not just the last row.

Comment: @user1603038: why would you expect that? The code clearly says, "`/* return number of observations if relationship is never TRUE */`". ;) Just change the C function to return `NA_INTEGER` if that's what you want. As I said, the function was written for a specific use-case and isn't particularly general.

Comment: Didn't notice that comment, sorry.

Comment: @user1603038: no worries, I was being sarcastic anyway. You might run into other things like that, but you can always alter the code and re-compile using `R CMD SHLIB`.

Comment: @user1603038: `NA_REAL` is special `NaN`, and the IEEE standard basically says that comparisons with `NaN` yield `false`.

Comment: Thanks! I already found it in http://adv-r.had.co.nz/C-interface.html and therefore removed my comment.

Answer (score 4):

That's a nice question and answer... just to add `any()` is no faster than `which()` or `match()`but both are quicker than [] which I guess may create a big vector useless T,F's. So I'm guessing No ..short of the answer above.

```
    v=rep('A', 10e6)
    v[5e6]='B'
    v[10e6]='B'

    microbenchmark(which(v=='B')[1])
    Unit: milliseconds
                   expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
     which(v == "B")[1] 332.3788 337.6718 344.4076 347.1194 503.4022   100

    microbenchmark(any(v=='B'))
    Unit: milliseconds
              expr      min      lq   median       uq      max neval
     any(v == "B") 334.4466 335.114 335.6714 347.5474 356.0261   100

    microbenchmark(v[v=='B'][1])
    Unit: milliseconds
               expr      min       lq  median       uq      max neval
     v[v == "B"][1] 601.5923 605.3331 609.191 612.0689 707.1409   100

    microbenchmark(match("B", v))
    Unit: milliseconds
               expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
    match("B", v) 339.2872 344.7648 350.5444 359.6746 915.6446   100
```

Any other ideas out there?

Comment: As the OP said, profiling indicates that >80% of the time is spent in the relational operators, so you shouldn't expect anything more than marginal speed improvements as long as you still use `==`.

Comment: Indeed I was just curious if `any` or some other function might be coded to stop when it found something hence doing less ==. Apparently not. Even then it wouldn't be a general solution.

Comment: Creating the logical vector is time-consuming, so any R function that requires a logical vector (e.g. `any`) won't help. Also, any function that unconditionally operates on an entire object won't help. As I said in my answer, I couldn't figure out a way to do this in pure R... which isn't to say I didn't try. In my case, `Data` was sorted and the usually-speedy `findInterval` didn't help much.