# How to split df into smaller parts by keeping id's intact

Tags: r

How to split large dataframe into smaller parts of approx. equal length so that some rows with identical `id` do not fall into next parts.

Here some toy data:

```
x <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,2),rep(3,3),rep(4,2)),r1=rep(1,10),r2=rep(2,10))
```

So how to split the above df into approx. equal size df's (list of df's) so that the `id` remains intact?

Desired output: `here we split x into approx. 3 equal parts`

```
[1] 
    id r1 r2 
 1   1  1  2 
 2   1  1  2 
 3   1  1  2 

[2]
     id r1 r2 
 4   2  1  2 
 5   2  1  2 
 9   4  1  2 
 10  4  1  2

[3]
    id r1 r2 
 6   3  1  2 
 7   3  1  2 
 8   3  1  2
```

**EDIT 1** Let's suppose we split the `x` so that each part contains approx. 3 rows of original df. So here is what I **don't want:

```
seqrow <- seq(1,nrow(x),3)
splts <- rep_len(1:length(seqrow), nrow(x))
lstdf <- split(x, f=splts)

lstdf
$`1`
  id r1 r2
1  1  1  2
5  2  1  2
9  4  1  2

$`2`
   id r1 r2
2   1  1  2
6   3  1  2
10  4  1  2

$`3`
  id r1 r2
3  1  1  2
7  3  1  2

$`4`
  id r1 r2
4  2  1  2
8  3  1  2
```

So we have here the max. 3 rows for each df but we see that the `id's` are scattered over each part separately.

Comment: your wording is bad. Seems like you do not understand what you wrote. Can you reformulate and put an example of desired output?

Comment: thanks for you comment. I hope now its fine.

Comment: why not 2 equal part (id 3 and 2 for the first data.frame and id 4 and 1 for the scond data.frame) ?

Comment: fine, it could be your way :)

Comment: This looks like a variant of the [bin packing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) (or knapsack) problem. Optimal solutions will be hard to find. Perhaps for your application it's enough to subdivide the list of unique IDs into 3 equal parts?

Comment: Have you thought about extract rownames() -> cbind() to original df -> split df -> make rownames() -> drop column with extracted rownames()

Comment: @krlmlr: no just approx. The point is just to retain the `id's` together, so that the sequence of id's is not split and doesn't appear in the next part...

Comment: Will you be specifying the desired number of bins?

Comment: And what size problems do you hope to apply this to (how many `id`s, and how many bins)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have an estimate of the intended number of rows in each subset, i.e. bin.

The following code starts to fill up the bins, starting with the biggest id-subsets. Then is successively adds still fitting id-subsets into the bin until the maximum number of rows in the bin is reached.

```
x <- data.frame(id=c(rep(1,2),rep(2,2),rep(3,3),rep(4,2)),r1=rep(1,9),r2=rep(2,9))

splitDfId <- function(
    ### Split dataframe into subsets, 
    ### keeping rows with same identifier together
    x               ##<< dataframe to split
    ,id             ##<< factor so that lines of equal level are grouped into the same subsets
    ,maxBinSize=4   ##<< number of rows in each subset
){
    dfCntBin <- data.frame(cnt=sort(table(id), decreasing =TRUE), bin=0L )
    # bins must be as big as the maximum number of equal level
    maxBinSize <- max( dfCntBin$cnt, maxBinSize)  
    #
    toBin <- 1:nrow(dfCntBin)
    while( length(toBin) > 0 ){
        binNr <- max(dfCntBin$bin)+1
        binCnt <- 0
        # first entry in toSort is the first matching entry
        # matching: still suiting into the bin
        matchFirst <- 1
        while( !is.na(matchFirst) ){
            i <- toBin[matchFirst]
            dfCntBin$bin[i] <- binNr
            toBin <- toBin[-matchFirst]
            binCnt <- binCnt + dfCntBin$cnt[i]
            freeCnt <- maxBinSize - binCnt
            matchFirst <- if(freeCnt==0) NA else {
                which( dfCntBin$cnt[toBin] <= freeCnt)[1]}
        }
    }
    #
    dfCntBin$id <- rownames(dfCntBin)
    xBin <- merge(x, dfCntBin)
    ##value<< a list of subsets of the data frame
    split(x, xBin$bin)
}

splitDfId(x, x$id)
splitDfId(x, x$id, 6)
splitDfId(x, x$id, 3)
```

If performance is an issue, then the search for the first still matching subset: `which(dfCntBin$cnt[toBin] <= freeCnt)[1]` can still be [speeded up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246903/faster-way-to-find-the-first-true-value-in-a-vector).

Comment: (+1), Thanks! On the sample data provided it works as expected. I'm yet to see how it is going to workout speed-wise on my real data as I have 1,5GB of data to split.

Comment: If the philosophy (of sorting by largest still fitting subsets into bins) is working for your problem, there may be faster alternatives. One could create a map on nrow(subset) -> list of ids with of subsets of this length. This will require some more track-keeping of the non-bin-assigned subsets but will not require searching the id-subsets.

If the dataframe merge in R is too slow, then one could do an excursion using a database (putting x and xBin to tables and let the database do the merge)