# downsampling a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, sampling, downsampling

I have a matrix Q that is relatively high dimensional (100X500000), and I want to downsample it. By downsample, I will explain with an example.

Let Q =

```
1 4 9
3 2 1
```

and downsample size= n. I want to draw n balls from a jar of sum(Q) = 20 balls, each ball colored 1 of 6 ways corresponding to a different index pair of the matrix. It's like I have 1 ball of color A, 4 balls of color B, etc, and I'm drawing n balls without replacement.

I want it to be returned in the same format, as a matrix.  One example return value, for example, downsample(Q, 3) =

```
0 0 2
1 0 0
```

My approach is trying to use sample:

```
sample(length(as.vector(Q)), size=n, replace=FALSE, prob = as.vector(Q))
```

However the problem with this is, sample considers 1:length(as.vector(Q)) as all the balls I have, so I can't draw more than length(as.vector(Q)) balls since I'm not replacing my balls.

So then to adapt my method, I would need to update my prob by subtracting 1 from this vector, and call sample one by one using a for loop of some sort.  It doesn't sound like nice code.

Is there a better way to do this in a R-friendly, no for loop way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little inefficient, but if `sum(Q)` isn't *too* large you can do this by disaggregating/replicating the vector and then sampling, then reaggregating/tabulating.

```
Q <- setNames(c(1,4,9,3,2,1),LETTERS[1:6])
n <- 10
set.seed(101)
s0 <- sample(rep(names(Q),Q),
       size=n,replace=FALSE)
Q2 <- table(factor(s0,levels=names(Q)))
## A B C D E F 
## 1 2 5 1 0 1
```

I'm not sure about your matrix structure. You could use `dim(Q2) <- dim(Q)` to reorganize the results in the same order as your original matrix ...

Comment: Great, I'll try this out.  Fyi I won't be able to use LETTERS b/c of dimensionality, but I'll just use names = [1:length(as.vector(Q)]

Answer (score 3):

Here's one way that's pretty good. You could improve its efficiency (if necessary) by replacing `which(x <= cq)[1]` with a function special-built for [finding the first TRUE value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20246903/903061).

```
Q = matrix(c(1, 4, 9, 3, 2, 1), nrow = 2)

set.seed(47)
samp = sample(sum(Q), size = 3)
cq = cumsum(Q)

inds = table(sapply(samp, function(x) which(x <= cq)[1]))

result = integer(length(Q))
result[as.integer(names(inds))] = inds
dim(result) = dim(Q)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    0    2    0
# [2,]    0    0    1
```