# Lazily evaluate that all elements of a vector are TRUE?

Tags: r

I'm working with long vectors, trying to test if all their elements are TRUE.  This happens to be pretty unlikely, so I was hoping `all(myvector)` would return FALSE as soon as it finds one FALSE value. That appears not to be the case.

```
system.time( all(rep(T, 100000000)) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.321   0.102   0.423 

system.time( all(c(F, rep(T, 100000000), F)) )
   user  system elapsed 
  0.444   0.211   0.655
```

Any way I can speed this up?

Comment: Most of the time in your example is being taken constructing the vectors!

Comment: Derp! Deleting this...

Comment: don't delete yet please.

Comment: just out of curiosity.. won't `sum(myvec )==length(myvec )` be faster? It will still add all once, but addition would be faster than comparison. [Ref  ](https://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2012-07-16/how-expensive-is-an-operation-on-a-cpu/). `system.time` seems to confirm that for me.

Comment: @Ben have you seen [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20247239) by Joshua Ulrich? It isn't exactly what you are looking for, but could be augmented to fit this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the time taken in your example was in constructing the vector. However, you can sometimes speed this sort of thing up with Rcpp, as explained in the [Rcpp chapter of Hadley Wickham's Advanced R book](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html).

It turns out that `any()` *is* lazy.  Rewriting it in C++/Rcpp actually slows it down in the lazy (TRUE-first) case, because the call to C++ has a bit of overhead, but speeds it up in the non-lazy (TRUE-last) case (my guess is that the speedup is because `any()` in base R has to do some other stuff like check for `NA` values ...)

```
x3 <- c(TRUE, rep(FALSE,1e7)) ## fast if lazy
x4 <- c(rep(FALSE,1e7),TRUE)
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction("
bool any_C(LogicalVector x) {
  return is_true(any(x));
}")

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(any(x3),any(x4),any_C(x3),any_C(x4))
      expr       min         lq        mean     median         uq       max
   any(x3)     1.224     1.6210     7.70592     9.1690    10.6430    53.431
   any(x4) 18255.964 19069.7740 20104.43401 19501.6215 20028.3585 35843.360
 any_C(x3)     2.850     4.3735    15.94341    14.4195    24.1195    85.295
 any_C(x4)  7782.388  8279.9395  8832.22210  8700.9380  9161.2205 12339.606
```

Comment: Thanks Ben.  I wanted to delete my embarrassing question but I certainly can't now, thanks to this informative answer.  Also, I had a feeling someone would suggest Rcpp.  Seems to be the go-to solution for writing simple, fast methods.